# Internal microphone doesn't work on Dell Vostro 3360

Tags: linux, laptop, alsa

I've got Dell Vostro 3360 laptop, and internal mic doesn't work. I use 3.8
series kernel.

When I try to record sound from mic I get only weird noise. All sliders in
alsamixer are 100% and capture is ON.

alsa-info.sh script output could be found [here](https://gist.github.com/a043fcf2686076d3e48f).

I guess it could be fixed by specifying model for snd-hda-intel module but I've
got no idea what model I should specify.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a hardware problem?

Comment: @peterph any idea how to check that?

Comment: Try with external mic. Alternatively try another installation (different distro or windows if that is an option).

Comment: It works indeed. I've compiler 3.9-rc6, and my mic works OK now. I think it happened due to large HDA sound rework in 3.9. Fortunately, I can use -rc kernels :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.9-rc6 kernel fixes this issue.